# error when using classifiers on data in python

Tags: python, random-forest, gaussian, svc

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
train_x, train_Y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=118,
                       n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                       random_state=0, shuffle=False)
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
classifier.fit(train_x, train_Y)
pred_y = classifier.predict(test_x)
results = confusion_matrix(test_Y, pred_y)
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-35e0e56a4410> in <module>()
      8 
      9 
---> 10 results = confusion_matrix(test_Y, pred_y)
     11 error = zero_one_loss(test_Y, pred_y)
     12 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py in confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels, sample_weight)
    253 
    254     if labels is None:
--> 255         labels = unique_labels(y_true, y_pred)
    256     else:
    257         labels = np.asarray(labels)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in unique_labels(*ys)
    101     # Check that we don't mix string type with number type
    102     if (len(set(isinstance(label, string_types) for label in ys_labels)) > 1):
--> 103         raise ValueError("Mix of label input types (string and number)")
    104 
    105     return np.array(sorted(ys_labels))

ValueError: Mix of label input types (string and number)
```

Above is my code which is using random forest classifier on the data set that i have, the probelm arised when i want to create a confusion matrix. Every time i run it, it gives an error (`ValueError: Mix of label input types (string and number)`). I did the same for decision trees and SVC and it worked fine, but with random trees and Gaussian classier it gives this error. Can anyone help me navigate through this? Thank you ;)`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you have in variables which makes problem - if you have strings and numbers then you have to convert all to numbers.

Comment: see if its makes sense now

Comment: I will repeate: first use `print()` to see what you have in variables which makes problem - if you have strings and numbers then you have to convert all to numbers. If you use pandas then you can also check `test_Y.dtypes`, `pred_y.dtypes` to see what type of data you have.